# Which laptop should I buy for video editing & web browsing & some video games?

Tags: laptop, processor, intel

I am looking for a laptop for work and study. This laptop must be able to handle:

- Videoconferences e.g. Zoom or Meet
- Use Microsoft Office programs (Word, Excel, PowerPoint)
- Fast Internet browsing
- Programming e.g. Visual Studio Code, GitHub
- Video editing e.g. Camtasia
- Video games (rarely)

I am interested in the following 2 laptops because the shop is in my city:

1. **Notebook Dell Inspiron I3593-7872BLK-PUS Premium 15.6'' Intel Core i7 8 GB DDR4 (USD ~2.214)**
2. **Notebook Asus TUF Gaming FX505DV AMD Ryzen 7 (USD ~2.280)**

Perhaps the most recommended is the Asus one because of processor minimum velocity (2.3 GHz instead of 1.3 GHz), but I have never used a gaming computer. I don't know about AMD processors either.

**UPDATE** Nos I hace to decide between these 2 laptops:

3. **Dell Inspiron 5593 i7 10th 32GB Geforce MX230**
4. **MSI Bravo 15 A4DDR Ryzen 7 32GB RX5500M**

In price they are very similar.

What do you suggest me to buy? 3 or 4?

Comment: Videoconferences and office do not take much resources.  Coding itself does not take anything either but running your code may (or may not).  Hard core video editing is quite CPU hungry, and video games may be GPU hungry.  I'd say go for something like i7 or ryzen 4000 and 16GB ram.  What about portability, battery life?

Comment: @OttToomet thanks for the useful information! I don't know nothing about Ryzen, the Asus which has Ryzen 7 is as good as Ryzen 4000? The battery is not important, it could be 4-6 hours without charging.

Comment: Ryzen 7 is about the same thing as i-7 (just by intel).  Ryzen 4000 is series, about the same as generation for intel.  What you list has ryzen 3750H, i.e. ryzen 7 of the 3000-series.  There was quite a large performance increase b/w ryzen 3000 and 4000 (the latter is 2020 model), so if possible, go for the latter.

Comment: The answer would be tons of RAM (DDR4) plus many cores plus a good M.2 SSD plus a good graphics card with Cuda with lots of RAM.

Comment: HP Pavilion Gaming 16-a0027ns seems a good option. Also Dell G3, Dell Alienware or ASUS TUF Gaming A15 FX506LH-BQ034 are good options too

Answer (score 3):

Gaming machines do not necessarily make the best option for other work. They tend to have 3D capabilities that can mean 2D rendering suffers ... and, if you're doing pure video (as opposed to animation or VR) work, 2D will be of much greater significance to you than 3D - I go out of my way to avoid anything offering 3D graphics on my A/V devices, because I need fast 2D rendering, not 3D and don't want the extra latency (no matter how little it may be, any is more than none).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!! Now I am deciding between 2 laptops: Dell Inspiron 5593 i7 10th 32GB Geforce MX230 vs. MSI Bravo 15 A4DDR Ryzen 7 32GB RX5500M. In price they are very similar. Considering the specs of the question (Fast Internet browsing, Programming & Video editing), which of these 2 would you buy?

Comment: Ultimately, only you can answer that. The problem is that your needs now may not be your needs in the future and whatever decision you come to will impact it. How long do you intend to keep it? If only a couple or so years, it's less significant than if you intend to keep it five years. How often do you intend to do each of the tasks?

Comment: Internet browsing, you want a fast connection, but that's independent of your laptop unless it has a notoriously slow NIC (check). However, a slow graphics update, poor CPU performance, slow RAM, etc. will slow it down regardless - because they slow *everything* down.

Comment: Programming, you want cores .. lots of cores - you don't want to find yourself in the position of Gentoo users, who need two of everything (right down to the chipsets on the components), if they want to get anything done whilst they compile (I exaggerate, but you get the point).

Comment: Video editing, man you are gonna need CPU power (as many cores as you can get), the fastest SSD you can sell little (abducted) children's internal orgns for and RAM (*lots* of RAM). If you don't intend doing it often and/or won't be getting paid for it, you could let this one slide, perhaps, but if it's going to be with any regularity and/or you'll be trying to meet deadlines, *this* is where the money needs to go.

Comment: The best thing to do would be to look for reviews by people using the two machines for those specific purposes. Generic reviews aren't really worth the paper they aren't written on: video playback performance tells me something if it's *bad*, but nothing if it's 'good' - good by *whose* standards (Joe Punter or Jill Video Editor?)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to all those things that you mentioned above then you should make sure that the laptop has the following specs:

- A processor with more than 8 cores and speed more than 2 GHz. Intel I7 or I9 10 gen will be good.
- A laptop that has 16GB of Random Acces memory.
- A laptop that has Nvidia or AMD GPU.
- A "Fast Internet browsing" depends on the ISP, a laptop can not make the internet fast.

There is a laptop named "Razer Blade 15", which is good for those things you have mentioned above. [Click here to buy from Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07D37VBVD)

If you are interested in those 2 laptops which you have mentioned above then I recommend you to go for 2nd one.

AMD Ryzen 7 is better than Intel Core i7.

Comment: Do laptops with >8 cores even exist?

Comment: Thanks for the specs!! Unfortunately that laptop costs $1000 more than I expected (not considering the shipping Cost which is $995).

Comment: Now I am deciding between 2 laptops: Dell Inspiron 5593 i7 10th 32GB Geforce MX230 vs. MSI Bravo 15 A4DDR Ryzen 7 32GB RX5500M. In price they are very similar. Considering the specs of the question (Fast Internet browsing, Programming & Video editing), which of these 2 would you buy?

Comment: I would have bought MSI Bravo 15 A4DDR Ryzen 7 32GB RX5500M. MSI is a good laptop company. MSI manufacture High-End Laptop. Dell Inspiron 5593 has i7-1065G7 and is not as powerful as Ryzen 7 4800H which is there is MSI. R7 4800H has 8 cores and 16 threads and i7 has only 4 cores and 8 threads. So I will choose MSI Bravo 15 A4DDR Laptop because it is better than Dell Inspiron 5593.